# get_object_or_404 can't find object with primary key

Tags: python, django, postgresql, web

My function in views.py is:

```
def detail(request,pk):
  singlepost=get_object_or_404(iblog,pk=pk)
  return render(request,'blog/blogpost.html',{'singlepost':singlepost})
```

My databse has several items but it return 404 error why ?
Also i use

```
path('<int:pk>/',views.detail,name='detail')
```

for mapping url and calling detail function in views.py
i test other parts of my project without get_object_or_404 function and every thing go right 
My problem is in primary key
How can i resolve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: what happens when you print out `pk`?

Comment: how do u pass a `pk` to the link in your templates?

Comment: Are you sure the pk that you're using exists in database?

Comment: @ritlew it returns id which entered in url for example when url is  http://localhost:8000/blog/1/  it returns 1

Comment: `iblog` is the name of your model, correct?

Comment: @sP_ i don't have primary key in database but i think django has add primary key as ID field to database automaticly

Comment: @ritlew yes iblog is my model name

Comment: are you sure the view is running? are you putting the trailing `/` on your url?

Comment: @MohammadAnsari Yes it does. But if you delete an entry that number is skipped. So check and see if the pk you're using exists. Default primary key attribute added by django to the model is `id`.

Comment: @ritlew yes i put / in my url path('<int:pk>/',views.detail,name='detail')

Comment: @sP_ thanks my friend you find problem i solved this problem thanks very much

Comment: @MohammadAnsari Glad I could help. I've written it in the answer form. If it helped you solve your problem, consider accepting it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the primary key that you're trying to access doesn't exist in the model. This can happen if you delete some objects.
Default primary key attribute added by Django to the model is `id`. Check if you're accessing a valid object and try again.

Comment: You do realize that pk is a standard Django alias for primary key?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#the-pk-property

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. I suggested checking the `id` attribute in case he's using some kind of database viewer. In python `id` and `pk` should both work fine.